# Creating a Map inside Iframe based on an Address using mapquest

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, html

This was the code I used to display map iframe:

```
<iframe
  src="@("http://media.littlecaesars.com/store/mapdev.html?address="+Model.StoreInfo.StoreInfo[0].ShortAddress.City +", "+ Model.StoreInfo.StoreInfo[0].ShortAddress.State +" "+ Model.StoreInfo.StoreInfo[0].ShortAddress.Zip)"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px"
></iframe>
```

**OR**

```
<iframe
  src="@("http://media.littlecaesars.com/store/mapdev.html?address=Troy,Michigan 48083")"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px"
></iframe>`
```

but this was making map to zoom out completely like below.

[image: Zoomout Image]

I suspect there is wrong with this **"@(** since I tried without this by using a static address which was showing me exact position. Since I was trying Variable address based on input parameters I was suppose to use **"@(**. Could someone help on this.

[Note: This code was written in cshtml page]

Answer (score 0):

That iframe seems to work fine, so it's probably something wrong with the cshtml.

```html
<iframe
src="http://media.littlecaesars.com/store/mapdev.html?address=Troy,Michigan%2048083"
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</iframe
```

Try right-clicking on your iframe and selecting "inspect element". Scroll up until you find the iframe and see what it says in `src`.

Comment: Yes, same this I mentioned above. It works perfectly like this        '<iframe
src="http://media.littlecaesars.com/store/mapdev.html?address=Troy,Michigan%2048083"
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</iframe>' but doesn't when it is like this '<iframe
  src="@("http://media.littlecaesars.com/store/mapdev.html?address=Troy,Michigan 48083")"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px"
></iframe>` .... I was suppose to use @

Comment: @Jaggi Can you inspect the broken map? I think its src will have an error somewhere.

Comment: @Jaggi Can you please paste what you found in the src when you inspected your iframe? I think using `@()` is changing the URL somehow, so I want to see what the URL is after the cshtml is rendered in the browser.

Comment: @Jaggi ok, I set up a local server to test this, and the src seems fine. Is the map hidden at the beginning? I.e. do you have to click to open it? Add the HTML surrounding the map to your question.

Comment: Yes I use a link button to open up this map in new popup window. I just want to clarify you that using lat and lang [...."@"("http://....?Lat & lang..")"...] instead of address,  map was zooming perfectly as required. I use javascript to fix the zoom position and please check any correction to be done here. Code is shown below:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   var getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
    var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
   };

Comment: var storelat = getQueryString('lat'); 
   var storelong = getQueryString('long');
   var storeaddress = getQueryString('address');

   window.onload = function() {
    var mapLayer = MQ.mapLayer(), map;
    var myIcon = L.icon({
     iconUrl: 'lceicon.png',
     iconRetinaUrl: 'lceicon.png',
     iconSize: [34, 49],
     iconAnchor: [17, 49],
     popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    });

Comment: if(storelat && storelong){
     map = L.map('map', {
      layers: mapLayer,
      center: [ storelat, storelong],
      zoom:16,                                   /*initial zoom level of map*/
      latLng:{lat:storelong, lng:storelong},
      mtype:'map',                               /*map type (map)*/
      bestFitMargin:10,
      zoomOnDoubleClick:true
     });
     
     L.marker([storelat, storelong],{icon: myIcon}).addTo(map)
    }

Comment: else if(storeaddress)
    {
     map = L.map('map', {
      layers: mapLayer,
      zoom:16,                                   /*initial zoom level of map*/
      mtype:'map',                               /*map type (map)*/
      bestFitMargin:10,
      zoomOnDoubleClick:true
     });

Comment: MQ.geocode().search(storeaddress)
      .on('success', function(e) {
       var best = e.result.best,
        latlng = best.latlng;
        
       map.setView(latlng, 16);
       
       L.marker([ latlng.lat, latlng.lng ], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
      });
    }
   }       
        </script>

Comment: @Jaggi edit your question instead, and put the code at the bottom. It's very hard to read here :)

Comment: this was solved after changing my URL to "https://mc.lcecorp.com/store/map.html?"